# Foreach loop Cannot convert char to System.Management.ManagementObject?

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a foreach loop that loops through all WMI services which only looks for certain services that contains specific key words to include and exclude. Therefore you can stop certain services that contains the included and excluded words. Unfortunately I'm receiving this error on the foreach loop that states Cannot convert type 'char' to 'System.Management.ManagementObject'. Hopefully you guys know. Thanks for the help.

```cs
public static void Test()
{
    string include = "SQL";
    string exclude = "EXPRESS, Writer";
    string[] includeArray = include.Split(',');
    string[] excludeArray = exclude.Split(',');

    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();

    //Scope that will connect to the default root for WMI
    ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2");

    //Path created to the services with the default options
    ObjectGetOptions option = new ObjectGetOptions(null, TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);
    ManagementPath spoolerPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Service");
    ManagementClass servicesManager = new ManagementClass(theScope, spoolerPath, option);
    using (ManagementObjectCollection services = servicesManager.GetInstances())
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject item in services.ToString().Where(x => includeArray.ToList().Any(a => x.ToString().Contains(a)) && !excludeArray.Any(a => x.ToString().Contains(a))))
        {
            if (item["Started"].Equals(true))
            {
                item.InvokeMethod("StopService", null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `in services.ToString().` should likely be just `in services.`

Comment: If I remove the ToString() then I receive the error that ManagementObjectCollection does not contain definition for Where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Linq on WMI objects like that.

What you can do is loop over the services and check the name: note also I removed the extra space in the `exclude` variable.

```cs
void Main()
{
    string include = "SQL";
    string exclude = "EXPRESS,Writer";
    string[] includeArray = include.Split(',');
    string[] excludeArray = exclude.Split(',');

    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();

    //Scope that will connect to the default root for WMI
    ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2");

    //Path created to the services with the default options
    ObjectGetOptions option = new ObjectGetOptions(null, TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);
    ManagementPath spoolerPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Service");
    ManagementClass servicesManager = new ManagementClass(theScope, spoolerPath, option);
    using (ManagementObjectCollection services = servicesManager.GetInstances())
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject item in services)
        {
            var serviceName = item["Name"];
            if (includeArray.Any(a => serviceName.ToString().Contains(a)) && !excludeArray.Any(a => serviceName.ToString().Contains(a)))
            {
                if (item["Started"].Equals(true))
                {
                    item.InvokeMethod("StopService", null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with Collections so you can use Linq easily, you can user [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi)

```
var list = helper.Query("select * from Win32_Service").ToList().Where(p => p.Contains("reserverWord"));
```